# Can I work only with complete atomistic boolean algebras instead of posets?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, article-writing

I wrote a book, most of whose theorems contain something like:

> $\mathfrak{A}$ is a poset with the following properties: ... Then the conclusion ... holds.

Now I am "slightly" rewriting my book with even more weak conditions. But even a slight rewrite is much work.

I wonder if I can replace $\mathfrak{A}$ with a complete atomistic boolean algebra (CABA) containing it and formulate my theorem only for complete atomistic boolean algebras only? Will this way work? Will we able to deduce theorems for posets from the special case of theorems for CABAs?

My question may look not specific enough. But it is just very general.

Please show examples (and if possible a general proof) of theorems for posets following from their special case for CABA.

Comment: This is new, at least to me. We're used to questions asking us to do the poster's homework, but here we have a question asking us to help the OP write a book. Remarkable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's much too general. We can't possibly know if your book can survive this change.  If you edit the question to ask about a particular theorem you wish to prove with your weakened hypothesis perhaps we can help.

Comment: @EthanBolker OK, I've asked a more particular question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2821698/4876

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Most my questions https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4876/porton?tab=questions (currently 320) are about writing my research book

Comment: Ok, so it's not "new". Hard to see what your point is in telling us that in writing  "your" "research book" you've asked 320 questions. Some might  think that before writing a book on a topic you should understand it well enough not to need that much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question:

From https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139810/embedding-a-brouwerian-lattice-into-a-boolean-lattice: "The embedding can be made to preserve all existing meets, or all existing joins (but not both at the same time)."

Theorems freely pass from CABAs to arbitrary orders only if all meets and joins are preserved. Otherwise need to take care about every meet or join :-(

So, the answer is "no".

Comment: Also choosing between cone (as defined in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139810/embedding-a-brouwerian-lattice-into-a-boolean-lattice) and co-cone, makes it possibly hard to choose just one of the two definitions.