# Embedding partial order into a powerset algebra

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Every partial order can be order-embedded into a powerset algebra (=complete atomic Boolean lattice) by mapping each element to the cone it generates.

Does this embedding preserve all existing meets and joins in the original partial order?

---

Also, does it preserve atoms and coatoms?

Comment: I think it is customary to call the cone generated by an element $x$ in a poset to the set of elements comparable to $x$, that is, to $$\{y:x\leq y\}\cup\{y:y\leq x\}.$$ If this is your definition, then in some posets you can have $a<b$ with the cone generated by $a$ not contained in the cone generated by $b$. Maybe you should clarify the embedding you have in mind.

Comment: @amrsa I use "cone" in the sense defined in https://mathoverflow.net/a/139828/4086

Comment: Supposing that what Emil Jerabek calls the cone generated by $a$ is the set $\{x:x\leq a\}$ (which is also a likely definition, and agrees to his Proposition 1), then you already have there the answer: "The embedding can be made to preserve all existing meets, or all existing joins (but not both at the same time)." Is it not clear?